# Finding a Random Variable $X$ on the sample space with given cdf

Tags: self-study, econometrics, cumulative-distribution-function, subset

*I will state the problem first, then follow through with my work.*

***Q:*** Suppose that the sample space is given by $S={w_1,w_2,w_3}$ where $w_1,w_2,w_3$ are three states of tomorrow's weather. We have the following $cdf$:
$$F(t)=\begin{cases} 
0 &\text{if }t<\frac{1}{2},\\ \frac{2}{3} &\text{if } \frac{1}{2}\le t<\frac{2}{3},\\ 1 &\text{if }t\ge\frac{2}{3}.\\
\end{cases}$$

Now I have to give an example of a field $\textbf{S}$ of $S$, probability $P$ on $\textbf{S}$ and a random variable $X$ on $S$ equal to the $cdf$ above.

***My work:***

Now the field  $\textbf{S}$ that I have come up with is: 
$$\textbf{S} = ([w_1],[w_2],[w_1,w_2,w_3])$$

My problem is that I am not sure how the variable $t$ comes into play here from the $cdf$ and especially how to get the random variable $X$. Help and guidance would be greatly appreciated!

*Many thanks in advance!*

Comment: You have to come up with a sigma-algebra, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma-algebra, which is a set that is characterized by certain properties. Have you looked them up? Because the $\mathbf S$ you propose does not satisfy them.

Comment: The cdf tells you about the set where the random variable is defined, i.e., which values it can take. This should simplify your resolution.

Comment: @Xi'an gives an excellent hint.  If I am counting correctly, assuming you avoid creating nontrivial sets of measure zero it will lead you to four different possible sigma algebras and $18$ different possible random variables having $F$ as their distribution, combining for $36$ distinct answers (with infinitely many choices of probability functions in many cases).

Comment: Thank you for the help. I understand the comments and the first part of the question, but coming up with the random variable is giving me some trouble still :/